# gdb - load kernel module for remote debugging

Tags: kernel, c, gdb

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS:

```
peter@peterubuntu0:$ insmod mymodule
peter@peterubuntu0:/sys/module/mymodule/sections$ cat .text .data .bss
0x0000000000000000
0x0000000000000000
0x0000000000000000
```

So how do I tell gdb where is my module loaded on target machine when I debug remotely? Do I use just the offsets (so 0x64 or 64 decimal for .text then?)?

```
peter@peterubuntu0:~$ objdump mymodule.ko --section-headers

mymodule.ko:     file format elf64-x86-64

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .note.gnu.build-id 00000024  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000040  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  1 .text         0000b345  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000064  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, CODE
 12 .data         000001e4  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00012620  2**5
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, DATA, LINK_ONCE_DISCARD
 15 .bss          00000014  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00012a80  2**3
                  ALLOC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add .gdbinit file to your home directory. Gdb sources this file when it starts. In this file you can define a macros for gdb and you can execute normal shell commands as well.

```
 #gdb implementation of the linux lsmod
 define gdblsmod
        set $current = modules.next
        set $offset =  ((int)&((struct module *)0).list)
    printf "Module\tAddress\n"

    while($current.next != modules.next)
                printf "%s\t%p\n",  \
                        ((struct module *) (((void *) ($current)) - $offset ) )->name ,\
                        ((struct module *) (((void *) ($current)) - $offset ) )->module_core
                set $current = $current.next
        end
end
```

This macro prints addresses of text sections for all currently loaded modules. Open gdb console and type `gdblsmod` to use this. You can put there also gdb commands like for instance:

```
set serial baud 115200
```

if you are debugging remotely over serial port.

Answer (score 1):

I found that, when the target is another xubuntu, also following works to obtain the text addresses:

```
(gdb) monitor lsmod
Module                  Size  modstruct     Used by
iptable_mangle         16384  0xffffffffc0f57040    1  (Live) 0xffffffffc0f55000 [ ]
...
```

then you can use the elsewhere documented commands to tell gdb the offset

```
(gdb) add-symbol-file mymodule 0xmymoduleaddress
```